# How can I dump my bootable ssd to inspect the dump in HEX editor

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, ssd, encryption

I am on macbook.
I have encrypted bootable volume. 
I know my password and can normally log in to my profile on macOs. 
I need to make byte-perfect dump of encrypted partition in it's decrypted state to search for a specific bytes sequence.
Steps I did:

- log in to recovery mode
- mount partition via diskutil
- run terminal and trying to read /dev/disk1s1

It shows following error:

```
cat: /dev/disk1s1: Operation not permitted
```

I also tried with hex editors and sudo mode.

Is there a way I can access unencrypted raw bytes sequence on internal ssd of my macbook?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are booting into recovery, you will need to decrypt it first using `diskutil`

```
diskutil coreStorage decryptVolume /dev/disk1s1 -passphrase ThePassPhraseYouSet
```

It will then decrypt the volume.

Per the man page (`man diskutil`) :

> Begin a live background process of decrypting the on-disk backing
>   bytes of an existing encrypted CoreStorage logical volume (LV).
>   **Bytes are read, decrypted, and written back to disk in plain form.**  The LV must be unlocked before beginning this operation.

You will have to unlock first...

```
diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume
```

Once it's unencrpyted, you can then use `dd` to dump it to an image for later manipulation:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/disk1 of=/path/to/disk.img
```

Comment: Excellent answer!